# Get a 403 error code when I trying to get a token from Auth0

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, auth0, bearer-token

I trying implement Auth0 authentication/authorization in web api. But get 403 error code (No such host is known. (https:443))

Simple code for get token is below

```
        var client = new AuthenticationApiClient(new Uri($"https://{ _config.GetValue<string>("auth0:Authority")}"));

        var authenticationResponse = await client.GetTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest
        {
            Audience = "https://dev-rignosgw.us.auth0.com/api/v2/",
            ClientSecret = _config.GetValue<string>("auth0:ClientSecret"),
            ClientId = _config.GetValue<string>("auth0:ClientId")
        });
```

But if execute analogous query in postman it is work correctly and i get auth token in response. Query is below

> curl --request POST \   --url
> 'https://dev-rignosgw.us.auth0.com/oauth/token' \   --header
> 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \   --data
> grant_type=client_credentials \   --data client_id=CLIENT_ID \
> --data client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET \   --data audience=https://dev-rignosgw.us.auth0.com/api/v2/

Question is folowing. What url must using in `AuthenticationApiClient` constructor? As I understand in my case it must beeen `ttps://dev-rignosgw.us.auth0.com/oauth/token`. Or I'm wrong?

I have never used Auth0 before. What i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You get a 403 so your user is not allowed to get a token, if route wasn't right, it would be a 404 error, be sure of your credentials in client secret and id

Comment: It's strange but I use the same parameter values in postman and get a token in response. May be initialization of AuthenticationApiClient is not propertly? If it helps, I can provide real values, because I using the test account on Auth0.

Comment: I was getting a 403 as well. I realized that I forgot to choose the permission scopes for my application. it's worth looking here as well if you get this error. Within the Auth0 console, go to Applications > APIs > Machine to Machine Applications. For the given app, expand the view to see the scopes.